# Tabview of setActiveItem(0) is not displaying content of page in sencha touch2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i have four separete view, adding these four view in single tabview as shown below.

**Tab View Code:**

```
Ext.define("SLS.BRND.WEB.view.MainTabbarView", {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'MainTabbarView',
    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.JsonP', 'Ext.TitleBar', 'Ext.Video', 'SLS.BRND.WEB.view.GallerysView', 'SLS.BRND.WEB.view.FloorView'],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        items: [
            {
                xclass: "SLS.BRND.WEB.view.GlobalNavigationView",
                docked: "top",
                scrollable: false
            },
            {
                xclass: 'SLS.BRND.WEB.view.ApartmentView'                    
            },
            {              
                xclass: 'SLS.BRND.WEB.view.SpecificationView'
            },
            {                
                xclass: 'SLS.BRND.WEB.view.FloorView'
            },
            {                
                xclass: 'SLS.BRND.WEB.view.GallerysView'
            }
          ]
    }
});
```

In controller onbuttontap function i am calling above 'MainTabbarView' page as shown below. i have set setActiveItem(0); to display first tabitem among four i.e (xclass: 'SLS.BRND.WEB.view.ApartmentView'). when i set like this setActiveItem(0) it will dispaly first view page but without data(blank screen).if i set like this setActiveItem(1), it will dispaly second view page with data. then i thought may be problem in first page, so i have changed order of page view in 'MainTabbarView'. again i set setActiveItem(0) then it showing active page but without data. i have keep on changed setActiveItem(0) to 1,2,3 its working fine and also data displaying. **but for the setActiveItem(0) data is not displaying**. can any help me . how to resolve this issue. thank you

**Controller Code :**

```
Ext.define("SLS.BRND.WEB.controller.ApartmentController", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],
    config: {
        refs: {
        projectsPage: "projectspage",            
            mainTabbarView: "MainTabbarView",         
        },
    control: {

            projectsPage: {               
               BtnApartments: "onAptButtonTap"               

            }
        }
  },
    onAptButtonTap: function () {
        var ApartmentTabbar = this.getMainTabbarView();
        ApartmentTabbar.setActiveItem(0);
        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(ApartmentTabbar, this.slideLeftTransition);
    },
    activateNotesList: function () {
        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(this.getHomepage(), this.slideRightTransition);
    },
    slideRightTransition: { type: 'slide', direction: 'right' },
    slideDownTransition: { type: 'flip', direction: 'down' },
    slideLeftTransition: { type: 'fade', direction: 'left' }

});
```

Comment: You've shown how the controller and view combine to display the 5 different panels (which is all working), yet not how the problematic panel is supposedly populated. Focusing on working navigation as the issue instead of data / store / model / view / components - who knows what the GlobalNavigationView is?!

Answer (score 0):

Your `onAptButtonTap` function is not in the right place, you put it in the config as you should put it after the config like so :

```
...
config: {
    refs: {
        projectsPage: "projectspage",            
        mainTabbarView: "MainTabbarView",         
    },
    control: {
        projectsPage: {               
           BtnApartments: "onAptButtonTap"  
        }
    },
    ...
},
onAptButtonTap: function () {
    var ApartmentTabbar = this.getMainTabbarView();
    ApartmentTabbar.setActiveItem(0);
    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(ApartmentTabbar, this.slideLeftTransition);
},
...
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i did mistake while posting code, function is outside of the config. as shown above code but facing same issue as above discussion. how can resolve this problem ?